# How do I start/stop mysql server?

Tags: sudo, mysql

I tried to find in some articles describing how to correctly start & stop mysql server.

I found this link: [How to start/stop MySql server on Ubuntu 8.04 | Abhi's Blogging World](http://abbysays.wordpress.com/2008/05/20/how-to-startstop-mysql-server-on-ubuntu-804/)

I ran this command:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

but I see this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000) Access denied for user....
```

After I tried this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

I entered my password, and again I see the same error.

Next command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql - root -p start
```

results in:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000) Unknown database 'start'.
```

And when I run this command:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

MySQL server success started. Cool!

So, what's wrong with the other commands? Why do they result in error?

Comment: In fact, even with sudo it didn't work for me, but then I found in the script the following hint: *Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)* and it was ok

Comment: Tim is correct.  Use *sudo service mysql start*.

Comment: Generally you can use sudo -l to see what your specific user on your specific system is allowed to do with sudo. (Your permissions are configured in /etc/sudoers.) However I don't know for sure if it would help in this particular case. EDIT: Wait, never mind, the access denied error looks like it is coming from MySQL or something, not sudo.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Your first two commands weren't run as root so that is expected behaviour. You need to be root to stop/start mysql.

However:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

should work. Indeed it does, for me:

```
kojan:~> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
[sudo] password for chris: 
Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld.
Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables..
```

I used restart rather than start, since it was already running, but the effect is the same. Are you sure you entered your password correctly? :) Have you edited your sudo config at all which would stop this working?

This one..

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql - root -p start
```

The arguments are wrong. an init.d script only takes `start` or `stop` or `restart` - just one word telling it what to do. You cannot give it multiple arguments as you were trying to do.

Anyway, the short answer is the one you actually got to work, is the recommended way. `service` is replacing all the init.d scripts over time, so you should get into the habit of using `service`. The page you link to was written in 2008, so has to be taken with some salt :)

Comment: Also try sudo service mysql start

Comment: `start mysql` worked for me (Ubuntu 12.04.4).

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` restarted MySQL for me

Comment: how about `sudo systemctl start mysql` for Ubuntu 16.04 and up?

Comment: this still worked for me on ubuntu 18

Answer (score 114):

Also helps to double check that "mysql" is the correct service name. In my case it wasn't. I kept getting following response:  mysql: unrecognized service when running

```
service mysql status
```

Then I checked /etc/init.d and found script named mysqld which listed process name: mysqld and prog=mysqld

So then I did

```
service mysqld status
service mysqld stop
service mysqld start
```

and they all worked fine.

edit: for new versions (MySQL 8) use

```
service mysql status
service mysql stop
service mysql start
```

Comment: `mysql: unrecognized service`

Comment: At least on 13.10, you'll need to run it with root privileges.  eg, "sudo service mysql status".

Comment: For 14.10 I needed to use "mysql" not mysql**d**

Comment: when running without root rights, it'll say `unknown job: mysql`. a bit confusing.

Comment: `Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found.`

Comment: @Green you need to install mysql-server `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and then run `sudo service mysql start`

Answer (score 36):

## For Ubuntu 12.10 to 14.04 ([Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/))

Newer versions of Ubuntu use [systemd](https://systemd.io/).

**START MYSQL:**

```
sudo start mysql
```

**RESTART MYSQL:**

```
sudo restart mysql # The service must be running
```

**STOP MYSQL:**

```
sudo stop mysql # The service must be running
```

Comment: `stop: Unknown job: mysql`

Comment: @Green I just tried this (one year later) and it is still working. This is my result: `mysql stop/waiting`. You must know that you have to be already running `mysql` to stop this ;)

Comment: Hero, you save my life, that mysqld has been occupied my machine memory for so long. I tried all kinds of methods to remove it, but all failed, until I met your answer.

Comment: `sudo: start: command not found`

Comment: @JCarlos Do `apt install upstart`

Answer (score 14):

I got a strange error when I installed mysql-workbench on my Ubuntu machine. After that I tried to start the mysql service using this command:

```
service mysql start
```

This showed that the MySQL server was not installed, so I installed it and my problem was solved. The command to install mysql-server is:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

After successful installation, start the MySQL server:

```
service mysql start
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu64 and I fixed by simply not using systemctl but instead this:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

hopefully this command will work for you.

Answer (score 7):

After installing MySQL on your system run this command:

```
service mysql status
```

If the service is down run:

```
service mysql start
```

To stop it:

```
service mysql stop
```

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysql start` and `service mysql start` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 4):

This one should work for the manually built mysql server:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04 the socket is defined in the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`:

```
 socket     = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

The directory was not present so I created it manually as below:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
```

Restart MySQL. That solved it for my case here.

Comment: This was definitely the case with mine!
Had to make a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck with the same issue. I uninstalled and reinstalled with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Answer (score 1):

use this command to start SQL server as the root user

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

OR

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Restart with this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Stop MySQL server with this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Check if MySQL is running:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Answer (score 0):

A little script to cover both cases [server running/server not running]:

```
#!/bin/bash

service mysql restart
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
  service mysql start
fi
```