# how to stop mysql server with root

Tags: mysql

How can i stop mysql server (installed using binary installation under `/usr/local/mysql`)?

When i go in `/usr/local/mysql/bin` and execute command

`mysqld stop` i get following error message :

```
[ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
[ERROR] Aborting
[Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

and i can still see process for mysql server.

same happens when i try to do it with mysqld in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: You have elected not to install the mysql package provided by Ubuntu and have instead manually installed a version into `/usr/local` - as such you are not doing things the normal "Ubuntu" way and the advice you get here may be affected.  That said, I'm sure people will still try and help as best they can.  But as a point of clarification - you should always use the Ubuntu-packaged versions of software unless you have a specific reason not to, and in that case you should mention that reason in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I start/stop mysql server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82374/how-do-i-start-stop-mysql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are running an up-to-date Ubuntu and you are already root, as you mentioned, the command is:

`service mysql stop`

or

`/etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Because of your installation, you should try this:

`sudo -u mysql /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld stop`

Comment: for service mysql stop : it gives following output - > mysql: unrecognized service                                              and for mysql stop : it gives following output - > ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'stop'

Comment: Please specify how did you installed your mysql server, also why you don't use the package version. We cannot really help you like this. Beside this you should run mysql server under mysql user and not as root. This is why it throws you errors.

Comment: i have installed using binary package  as described in "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//binary-installation.html" and i am running it under mysql usr  "/bin/sh bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql"

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: i did that and continuously getting following errors : InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11                                                               
i am really sorry but i am helpless

Comment: Forget about binary installation, remove it, and install mysql server with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6537/discussion-between-mangesh-jogade-and-frantique)

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo mysqld stop` to stop it as root.

hope it helped.

Comment: error occurred when i executed with root.

Comment: Then, are you sure you are in the sudo'ers file? That you are allowed to use "sudo" ? Find the process and kill it with `pkill`, find it by reading the list on `ps -e`.

Comment: 1) i was looged in as root                                                              2) i can kill the process, but why i am not able to stop it with mysqld ? is it any bug???

Comment: mysqld is the file that runs, you can end the file, but the process will remain running in the background. So you just have to kill the process manually.

Comment: i want to stop it using mysqld only.

Comment: sorry, but i dont have any idea how to do that if that above didnt work. Yeah, sorta bug if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

should do it.

Comment: i am already a root

Answer (score 1):

You have elected not to install the mysql package provided by Ubuntu and have instead manually installed a version into `/usr/local` - as such you are not doing things the normal "Ubuntu" way and the advice you get here may be affected.

The normal way of install MySQL in Ubuntu is by installing the package provided by Ubuntu using something like `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.  Installing something manually into `/usr/local` with a make or install script should be something done only when you have a specific reason to do so and you have a greater level of technical skill and knowledge, and willingness to set it up correctly yourself. You'll also need to do updates and security patches manually because it won't be done by Ubuntu.

Based on your level of technical knowledge of Ubuntu I don't think installing something manually into `/usr/local` is for you.  Unless you respond with a good reason for not being able to use the one included with Ubuntu and you really want to learn more, I'd advise removing that MySQL and installing the Ubuntu one with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.

After doing this, you'll be able to follow all the normal instructions you find on the Ubuntu wikis and howtos.

Answer (score -2):

try the following:

quit;

this worked for me...then i just got the msg: "bye". then it was showing again to enter a comand as the USER@user>, not as MYSQL>. Help this works!

Comment: This shows how to quit the command line client but the question is about how to stop the server.