# Cannot install mysql on Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome 3.26.2

Tags: apt, server, package-management, dpkg, mysql

Trying to install mysql, I always get the following error:

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

See in full below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,184 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 283762 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[I have tried this solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322637)
as well as almost every solution available on stackoverflow but it doesn't solve my problem
Even mysql server is not entirely removed by `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server`. I've to remove it by using synaptic manager

**What worked for me:**
Disabling all the third party repositories and the following the linked question instruction again

Comment: If you have really tried "every solution available on stackoverflow", then please edit your question to tell us exactly what you tried, and exactly what each result was.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql service is allready running on your system.
try

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

or read this: [How do I start/stop mysql server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82374/how-do-i-start-stop-mysql-server)

after that, you should check which version of mysql is installed and see if you actually need a different version.

Comment: Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.

Comment: Try to clean out the apt-cache too, you have 6 packages not upgraded, and 2 suggested packages. try apt-get clean and apt-get autoremove

Comment: this maybe stupid, but have you tried simply rebooting your system?

Comment: Nopes it didn't worked. I thing the main problem here is " Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceFailed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
 failed!"

Comment: Nopes I've tried almost everything that is available on net but not rebooting

Comment: Now, I've tried rebooting. I didn't helped. Its showing unmet dependencies but `apt --fix-broken install` couldn't fix this

Comment: try to remove the broken packages, sudo apt-get remove -f , sudo dpkg --configure -a ,sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get update , sudo apt-get upgrade , sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: Same error is encountered in all these commands :(

Comment: can you tell me which packages have unmet dependencies? also, do you have any third party repositories?

Comment: mysql-server-5.7 itself has unmet dependency. I believe I do have some third party repo but not many I think some ppa and canonical repo are there

Comment: disable those repo's first before trying those commands again, could be they're the source of the dependency issues

Comment: I've tried after disabling all the 3rd party repo but it didn't helped at all

Comment: keep them disabled until the system is clean. what unmet dependencies are there, and what are they conflicting with?

Comment: Plz take a look at this https://pastebin.com/Q3iNYU68

Comment: is mysql-common installed on your system? try removing mysql-server and mysql-server-5.7, then apt-get clean and apt-get autoremove and install them again. They were installed but not configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your constant support @Glenn van Acker but this solved my problem https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/665275

Comment: good, perhaps you can answer your own question here, and mark it, so others can benefit of this information?